# "moved to chat" link leads to page containing both a barely readable "object moved to here" and a "page not found" notice

Tags: bug, chat

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/107333/2509) contains a "moved to chat" link as a sole comment:

> are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70847/discussion-on-answer-by-alamar-how-much-if-anything-can-i-get-in-compensation)

The resulting page has a big "Page not found" notice.  Hidden in the top-left corner, almost invisible due to the top status bar, is the text *Object moved to here.*, which links to the correct page.  Thus:

- There are two inconsistent notices.  If Stack Exchange knows where this page has moved to, that means it's found.  Yet it also says it's not found.
- The text "Object moved to here" is barely readable due to the top status bar.

The solution should probably be to send a HTTP Redirect.

Comment: Is this a systemwide bug? The link is an http URL; the "here" links to the https URL. EDIT And now the last message is "This room has been automatically deleted for inactivity."

Comment: It's yet another http - https bug IMHO. If you prefix the url with https [it works](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70847/discussion-on-answer-by-alamar-how-much-if-anything-can-i-get-in-compensation).

Comment: @choster I don't know.  I don't know what triggers it.  Does it happen when a chatroom gets moved perhaps?